# python package ggtools couldnot import ggtools.gg

Tags: python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\ggtools\gg\__init__.py", line 116, in <module>
    from .gsm_utils import print_gsm_date_coverage,gsm_download,read_gsm,gsm_average
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\ggtools\gg\gsm_utils.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .utils import print_error_grace
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\ggtools\gg\utils.py", line 2, in <module>
    from sphericalpolygon import create_polygon
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sphericalpolygon\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .create_polygon import create_polygon
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sphericalpolygon\create_polygon.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .polygonclasses.sphericalpolygon import Sphericalpolygon
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sphericalpolygon\polygonclasses\sphericalpolygon.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ..inside_polygon import inside_polygon
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sphericalpolygon\inside_polygon.py", line 2, in <module>
    from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
    from .qhull import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was that the create_polygon function was replaced with 'from_array' and 'from_file' in version 1.2.1 of sphericalpolygon. Downgrading to version 1.2.0 solved the issue: pip install sphericalpolygon==1.2.0